# Processing: Why does this sketch not work in Javascript mode?

Tags: javascript, processing

For some reason, and I'm not sure why, my Processing sketch doesn't display in JavaScript mode. However, in Java mode it runs how it's intended. I'm pretty sure that everything used is in the Processing API, so I really have no idea why this doesn't work.

A rundown on the program. Basically, I had to create a Stock Ticker with text moving from bottom right of the screen to the left on a constant loop.

Stock Ticker:

```
Stock[] quotes = new Stock[12];
float t=0;
PFont text; 

void setup() {
  size(400,200);
  //Importing "Times" font 
  text = createFont( "Times" ,18,true);

 //Assigning Strings and Float values to Stock array index
  quotes[0] = new Stock("ADBE",68.60);
  quotes[1] = new Stock("AAPL",529.36);
  quotes[2] = new Stock("ADSK",51.41);
  quotes[3] = new Stock("CSCO",21.87);
  quotes[4] = new Stock("EA",30.17);
  quotes[5] = new Stock("FB",67.07);
  quotes[6] = new Stock("GOOG",1201.52);  
  quotes[7] = new Stock("HPQ",31.78);  
  quotes[8] = new Stock("INTC",25.41);  
  quotes[9] = new Stock("MSFT",40.49);  
  quotes[10] = new Stock("NVDA",18.56);  
  quotes[11] = new Stock("YHOO",38.24);    

  //Assigning Position of indexs using setX method from Stock class
  float x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) 
  {
    quotes[i].getX(x);
    x = x + (quotes[i].width()); 
  }
  t = x; 
}

void draw() {
  background(55);
  //Rendering of Text using trans and show functions from Stock class
  for (int i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) 
  {
    quotes[i].trans();
    quotes[i].show();
  }
  //Transparent Rectangl;e
  noStroke();
  fill(10,10,10,127);
  rect(0,164,width,35);
}
```

Stock:

```
class Stock {
  String stockName; 
  float stockNum;     
  float x;     
  String show; 

  Stock(String n, float v) 
  {
    stockName = n;
    stockNum = v;

    show = (stockName + " " + stockNum + "   ");
  }

  //Sets position of each index
  void getX(float x_) 
  {
    x = x_;
  }
 //Moves text 
  void trans() 
  {
    x = x - 1;
    if (x < width-t) 
    {
      x = width;
    } 
  }

  //Renders Text
  void show() 
  {
    textFont(text);
    textAlign(LEFT);
    fill(255);
    text(show,x,height-10); 
  }
  //Records and returns width of index
  float width() 
  {
    textFont(text);
    return textWidth(show); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. According to Processing.js page, it does not work with most Java, so
   you need to be careful with what libraries you use. From their
   [Quick Start](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#implementationofjava) page:

   > Processing.js is compatible with Processing, but is not, and will
   >   never be, fully compatible with Java. **If your sketch uses functions or
   >   classes not defined as part of Processing, they are unlikely to work
   >   with Processing.js.** Similarly, libraries that are written for
   >   Processing, which are written in Java instead of Processing, will most
   >   likely not work.
2. Even if the libraries you use are supported, you have to be very
   careful while naming your variables because Javascript being a
   typeless language can result in variable name clashes that you
   wouldn't normally worry about when writing in Processing in Java
   mode (or in Java directly) since it is a typed language. See
   [Processing.js's note](http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#variablenamingcare) on this.

Comment: Okay, I thought it might have been something along those lines. Thanks,